# Running Dos Program With Background Worker VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

Part of my program runs a Dos application using

```
process.start("my app.exe")
```

and then my GUI is updated from the results of the Dos Application. The Dos application is continually scrolling data up the dos window and this data is then been shown in my GUI in a TextBox.

If I was to put the process.start onto a Background Worker would this run in a separate thread and help free up my GUI to do other things without slowing it down ?

Comment: If you're continuously updating your GUI with the output, then your app is going to have a continuous problem refreshing itself.  Doesn't matter if you wrote everything correctly with respect to threading.  Find a balance between usability and interval of refreshing.  You can use threading to queue the output, and update the GUI from that queue at a different rate or through some kind of user directed mechanism.  Without more details about the app and how the user will use the output, this whole discussion is probably not very hepful...

Comment: I haven't seen any refreshing issues so far but how you have brought it o my attention, I shall look into this deeper. Thank You

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, my thinking on this would be process.Start(my app.exe) would already be on a separate thread, so really what I think you're needing is how to hook up some form of messaging back from your dos app.  Would that be right?